# Spring MVC Monitor / Watch Every Request

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is it possible to monitor every Spring request that comes in?

Something like:

```
public class MySpringWatcher extends SpringSomething{

    @Override
    public HttpServletResponse watchResponse(HttpServletRequest request){

        // Starts a timer and counter for analyzing each request made
        MyTimerCounter timerCounter = new MyTimerCounter(request);

        //Do the request, process Java and JSTL Code
        request.doSomething();

        // Mark complete and then log results
        timerCounter.stop();

    }

}
```

OR Perhaps

```
public class MySpringWatcher extends SpringSomething{

    MyTimerCounter activeRequest;

    @Override
    public SpringResponse beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request){

        // Starts a timer and counter for analyzing each request made
        activeRequest = new MyTimerCounter(request);

    }

    @Override
    public SpringResponse afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        // Mark complete and then log results
        activeRequest.stop();

    }

}
```

I want to monitor every request so I can analyze each and count SQL requests, times, etc., but I need to do it on each request, and for each controller.

It should start right before the controller method is called, and end right after the JSP completes.

I am using SpringMVC 4, Spring Boot, Spring Security, Morphia, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do it with a filter.

Comment: Thanks! So I just create a bean of for `MySpringWatcher` that extends `javax.servlet.Filter` and everything should work?

Comment: I did try this, but I must be doing it wrong because it runs the methods inside this command like 1000 times per request, and I just dont know how to get it to work.  The answer below really helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at HandlerInterceptors ([1.11.5 Interceptors](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors))

They will allow you to intercept requests both before and after handling.

---

Updating based on comment from [Nitroware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338844/nitroware):

If using spring boot/JavaConfig, in your MvcConfig you will want to add the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MySpringWatcher myInterceptor() {
        return new MySpringWatcher();
    }

    // ... The rest of your configuration ...
}
```

That will allow you to register your new HandlerInterceptor.

---

For xml based configuration see the link provided by [kmansoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688202/kmansoor%20kmansoor):

[http://www.journaldev.com/...](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I must be doing it wrong, when I use: `@Component public class MySpringWatcher extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {…}` and implement all the methods, the class is instantiated, but the methods are never called.

Comment: You do have an entry in the config file for your interceptor? Take a look at this: http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter

Comment: I am using spring boot, so there is no XML, however I did figure out what to do to compensate, in your `public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` add  ```@Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    MySpringWatcher myInterceptor(){
        return new MySpringWatcher();
    }```

Comment: Throw that into your answer for future readers, and I will mark it as accepted.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I went ahead and added the JavaConfig example you mentioned.  I don't think you need the @Autowired annotation you show, so I omitted that.  Glad to hear it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptors must be 'wired'. Either through the configuration xml or JavaConfig.